# Meteor collection undefined despite having the files in a lib directory

Tags: meteor, reactjs

After looking at the various comments on the net, most of which say, "put them in the lib directory", I'm still at a loss as to where to put my collections js files.  It seems no matter where I put them there is an issue. I've tried them in the client directory, lib directory, lib/collections directory. All to no avail. What else could I be missing.

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
export const Subjects = new Mongo.Collection('subjects');
```

Answer (score 1):

The immediate issue was in the way I was importing.  I had:

```
import Subjects from '../../../../lib/collections/subjects.js';
```

but the following fixed it:

```
import {Subjects} from '../../../../lib/collections/subjects.js';
```